# "InputMismatchException" error, counting lines in a file

Tags: java, android, arrays, java.util.scanner

How can I count the number of lines in a file?

Below is the code I have written, but with an exception.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
        String[] MovieList = new String[25];
        File MovieFile= new File("TheMovieList.txt");
        Scanner ms = new Scanner(MovieFile);
        while(true){
            int i= ms.nextInt();
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

And I had

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException

What's wrong, and how can I fix this?

Comment: This does not seem to relate to JavaScript.

Comment: I'm going to make a guess - you get the exception when calling `nextInt()` and it's probably because there is no integer there.

Comment: The input is not a valid int.

Comment: Whilst we’re not a debugging on demand service, I would guess nextInt is not getting an int.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To count the lines in the file you can do this.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
        File MovieFile= new File("TheMovieList.txt");
        Scanner ms = new Scanner(MovieFile);
        int count = 0;
        while (ms.hasNextLine()) {
            count++;
            ms.nextLine();
        }
        System.out.println("Number of lines in the file is " + count);
    }
}
```

Comment: My case is: I have a text file, and i want to count its line in an integer variable.

Am I doing it right?

Comment: No, you are not doing it right, the answer is edited based on your comment.

Comment: hope the edited answer is solving your problem to count the number of lines in the input file.

Comment: It is,
Thanx for your support Mr.Eby

Answer (score 0):

You can check, that the input can be interpreted as an int value:

```
...
if (ms.hasNextInt()) { 
  int i= ms.nextInt();
  ...
}
```